# How to correctly integrate libosmscout into a QT C++ project?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm attempting to integrate libosmscout into my C++ project developed in QT. Following the instructions provided on the official libosmscout documentation page [here](https://libosmscout.sourceforge.net/documentation/source/),

I have successfully downloaded and built the library (I hope so). However, I'm encountering difficulties in determining which specific library files are necessary for my project and how to properly include them.

Upon building libosmscout, I've noticed in my `*../libosmscout/build*` folder were created numerous library files spread across various folders such as *libosmscout*, *libosmscout-import*, and *libosmscout-map*, and other. Despite this, I'm unsure about the exact files essential for integration into my QT project and the correct procedure for adding them.

Could someone please provide guidance on identifying the necessary libosmscout files for a QT C++ project and the steps to incorporate them effectively? Any insights or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My expectation is you would look at the modules in the documentation to figure out what ones you want; [https://libosmscout.sourceforge.net/api-doc/html/modules.html](https://libosmscout.sourceforge.net/api-doc/html/modules.html)

Comment: There is a demo application here: [https://github.com/Framstag/libosmscout/blob/master/Demos/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/Framstag/libosmscout/blob/master/Demos/CMakeLists.txt)